# How to correctly handle System.Net.Mail.SmtpException?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a simple smtpClient:

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient { Host = host, ...};
smtp.Send(message);
```

I can have a different host: `smtp.gmail.com` , `smtp.yandex.ru` etc.

When `smtp.Send(message);` executed I have different exception (depends on the host) due to the same problem - 2-factor verification is off.

For gmail its `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.`

For yahoo and yandex its
`System.Net.Mail.SmtpException depth 0: The operation has timed out. (0x80131500)`

I don't now about others mail providers exception but how to correctly throw exception ("you need to enable 2-factor verification") just once? Is it possible? Or how to minimize code duplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are choosing which host to use (an `if` or `switch` statement?) but you could consider adding two new client classes which inherit from SmtpClient, e.g. for a YahooClient:

```
class YahooClient : SmtpClient {

     private const string Host = "smtp.yahoo.com";

     Send(MailMessage message) { 

          /// Call base send and handle exception            
          try {
             base.Send(message)
          }
          catch(ex as SmtpException) {
              // Handle accordingly
          }
     }
}
```

Furthermore, you could introduce implement a suitable interface and use IoC (or strategy pattern etc.) to inject the correct client based on your configuration, e.g.

```
class YahooClient : SmtpClient, IMySmtpClient {

}

interface IMySmtpClient {
    void Send(MailMessage message);
}

class ConsumingMailSender(IMySmtpClient client) {

       // Create message and send
       var message = new MailMessage etc....

       client.Send(message);
}
```

This is perhaps overkill but could avoid violating SRP and having to perform conditional logic in the method you are currently using to send the email in.

Comment: `host` it's a parameter in the method: `public void Send(string host)`

Comment: So instead of sending the host name as a string in the method, you would send the SmtpClient implementation.  This would normally be done using Dependency Injection.  You could also do it by new-ing up the appropriate SmtpClass client class (e.g. YahooSmtpClass) in a `switch` or `if` based on your configuration or other condition.

Comment: There is no need for different clients. But an error processor class that is selectable by host domain (from a config file) would work

Comment: You could use an error processor and that would be fine if there are two or three host domains. If the number of host domains increases though, the error processor class is going to get bloated and if-fy.